# Yii2 не работает action

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, mvc

Приложение на Yii2-advanced в common есть модуль support, в файле main.php в папке config он был подключен

```
'support'           => [
            'class' => \common\modules\support\Support::class,
        ],
```

Теперь я хочу сделать управление данным модулем через backend, создаю там контроллер SupportController в нужной папке и actionIndex, но при обращении в этому актиону у меня ошибка

> Not Found (#404)

Если я переименую контроллер допустим в SupportsController то все начинает работать, я так понимаю происходит конфлик имени подключения модуля и имени самого контроллера.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Думаю нужно смотреть в роутах что там у вас происходит

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan return [
    'login'                      => 'site/login',
    'view/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
];

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в урл менеджер правило

```
'/support/<action:\w+>' => 'support/<action>'
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло=(